# React native google sign in modal not always showing

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-oauth

I am working with google sign in react native with firebase. I just followed the docs, setup everything and it is working fine. The only problem i am facing is that it sometimes takes too much time (especially on app start) to show the modal with the google accounts. The screen greys out but the modal doesn't show up.

I am implementing phone number auth in my another project which is also using firebase (but different account). There also, the test numbers take too much time to receive otp.

So i just want to know if there is some problem with the firebase when we are in debugging mode or is there any extra thing to do to get rid of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to configure Google SignIn in useEffect method.

```
useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:
        'YOUR_WEBCLIENT_ID',
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Yeah, already done. I think this is a problem in developement mode on an emulator (android only). On a real device even in development mode and on ios emulator, it works fine.